# Getting error when Add 'Product Tier Prices' for Configurable products: Magento 2.3.2

Tags: admin, configurable-product, magento2.3.2, tiered-pricing

I am using Magento 2.3.2. When i am tring to add **Customer Group Price** for child product of configurable products in admin panel then i am getting below error when save the product:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '16092-1-0-30.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_6D3040166530765494A77D7288801D79', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `website_id`, `percentage_value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

but it's working for **Simple Products** as expected.

I am not able to understand why i am getting this error.

Once i have truncated that table but still getting **Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry**

**Any help??**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't add the tier price or even price for configurable products(except custom extension). If you want to add tier price for the configurable product then you need to add it in the child product.

Please check this and let me know if you need further information.

https://magecomp.com/blog/need-to-know-about-tier-price-for-configurable-products-magento-2/

Comment: yes you are right, I mean when i adding tier price for child product of configurable product then  i am getting that error but now i test this issue is coming with every product.

Comment: Let's do basic steps first, do indexing with reset and reindex all command and see if you are getting this issue or not.

Comment: i have done that steps many times and also delete that particular record from table catalog_product_entity_tier_price but still not working

Comment: Now try to remove third party extension and see it is working fine or not. If still it is not working then let me know I will help you in this. Email Me: nitish250788@gmail.com

Comment: After disable third party extension (Magesales_MultiStoreViewPricingTierPrice) its working for me. Thanks for the suggestions. happy coding...!!!

Comment: Please accept this as an Answer so it will help to others.